# abc news listning

Tags: american-english

From the 3:57 to 4:03 of the following video,
what is he(Spencor Stone) saying?

http://abcnews.go.com/Nightline/video/real-life-french-train-attack-heroes-recreating-incident-52924462

(it is not clear even though I read the transcript.)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

He's saying:

"We're like, 'Hey Clint, we might need some acting classes.' He said 'Nah, I don't want you to do that because then it's gonna look like you're acting.'"

He kinda spoke fast and rambled through Clint Eastwood's name which made it hard to understand. Hope this helps.

Comment: great thanks. really helpful. The later part is especially hard to hear for me.